# HTTP 1.1 keep-alive

Tags: google-chrome, http, safari, keep-alive, http-1.1

I have created an application using SpringBoot in backend and AngularJs in frontend. In chrome developer tool I can see in my XHR requests a header like this -

`Connection: keep-alive`

I know what **keep-alive** means in HTTP 1.1, which basically allows one to use an existing connection for more requests (**without TCP handshake** every time) until some condition matches like keep-alive timeout or maximum request par connection.

Out of curiosity, How can I check on a browser like Chrome or any other if actually a single TCP connection is used behind more than one XHR request the browser making to the server. Also if I misunderstood something please correct me here.